# What’s the difference between Architectural views, viewpoints and views?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I'm new in software architecture, and I'm struggling with these concepts?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the book 'Software Systems Architecture' by Nick Rozanski and Eoin Woods which has an entire chanpter on viewpoints and views.

The basic idea is that you cannot develop a single and complete architectural model for a complex system that will be understandable for all of the stakeholders of the system.

For this reason, it has turned out beneficial to create several representations of the model (called **views**) that show certain aspects which are important for a given stakeholder or a group of stakeholders.

As a tool to construct views, you can use some patterns or templates (called **viewpoints**) which help you to end up with well-structured and sensible views. A viewpoint should also define the concerns and intended audience of the corresponding view.

**Example:** A network adimistrator who must operate a system will not be very interested in internal data structures, but rather in communication structures and interfaces between components. So for the viewpoint, you would define what is meaningful for the network administrator and which types of documentation / diagrams etc. should be used as a description. The resulting view is a subset of the architectural model that you give to the network administrator.

Remember that an important part of an architect's work is the communication with different people.

Comment: So the viewpoint is a class, and the view is the object of the class